# How to do a server redirect of URL to a different URL if the traffic is accessing from static QR code

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, http, redirect

I've always found this forum helpful. So I'm faced with a big dilemma here and was hoping someone here could help :D
HERE'S THE SITUATION:
We have multiple static QR codes that were printed on thousands of boxes which have already been distributed that go to the wrong URL. Unfortunately the designer didn't make the QR code dynamic, so we don't have the option of editing the URL through the QR code generator's interface.

We are a white label manufacturer and provide packaging to tons of clients, so what happened was a batch of qr codes got put on the wrong brand's packaging and so as you could imagine its a huge mess. Hoping someone could help ya girl out! :D

I've decided that our best bet would be to implement automatic redirects of the individual pages on the server side. My question is, is there any type of script that would be able to redirect traffic ONLY coming from a QR Code scan?? I've heard of Bootstrap being able to route traffic based on device and browser, etc. So I'm remaining hopeful that someone has heard of a way of doing this. And if there is such magical code, what file or table to I need to edit? Btw I have phpmyadmin but no cPanel.

Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Side Note -

NO CPANEL! I'm using Wordpress 6.1 on wordpress managed hosting through GoDaddy - and so I do not have access to a cPanel unfortunately :(

I tried going through the QR code generator's interface to "edit" the URL of the QR Code, however the QR code was not created as dynamic. It is a static QR Code.

And lastly, the reason why we can't just simply sticker over the wrong QR code with a new one is because the boxes were already distributed.

- Danii

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what URL it goes to. If it goes to your site's domain, e.g. it shows a 404 page of your site or another page, then it is easy to fix. There are plugins for redirection and the most downloaded one and free is [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

1. Install the plugin
2. Go to the plugin's settings page
3. Open the tab "Redirects"
4. Add a new redirect at the bottom of the page

see the screenshot[image]